# My computer refuses to install OpenCV in Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, environment

After re-installing Anaconda 4 times in a row, and trying every possible trick in the book, I cannot seem to get OpenCV in my Anaconda apps. I want to use cv2 in Spyder (version 5.2.2), but countless tries have not resulted in anything of use.

DISCLAIMER: I am quite the noob when it comes to data environments, paths and whatnot, so be nice :)

INFO ABOUT THE PROBLEM:
I have now factory reset the computer, only downloaded and installed Anaconda through the official website. I then tried to type in to the Anaconda prompt:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

When I run that, it currently produces:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done                                                               
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.                                    
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next 
repodata source.             Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done                                                                       
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.                                    
Solving environment: /
```

I tried the same yesterday, with similar results. Running for a couple of hours, it started Examining conflicts with a bunch of packages.

At this point I can do no better than just ask here. I've tried so many different ways of trying to install openCV, and none of them have worked. I am desperate for any help.

I am using a GP66 Leopard computer with Windows 10, I don't know what more specs are needed.

In advance, thank you for looking in to this problem.

Comment: do not install from conda. install from pypi. `pip install opencv-python`. that's the **official package**. and install exactly one OpenCV package, not multiple. and make sure you aren't trapping yourself with any containers, virtual machines, or virtual environments, or your IDE picking the wrong python (how many do you have?)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz this seems like a common issue. Do you have a duplicate to recommend?

Comment: I've given up long ago. this site is hopeless. the fight against forces of nature is futile. _maybe_ i'll eventually whip up a userscript that lets me dump boilerplate more easily but that's all. marking as duplicate is pointless because most people can't be bothered to google/search.

Answer (score 2):

This did it: `pip install opencv-python`. Thank you to @CristophRackwitz for the suggestion!